# designing a supercapacitor balanced charger circuit

Tags: power-supply, charging, supercapacitor, cell-balancing

I'm currently designing a super capacitor based emergency power supply for a system. The operating voltage of my system is around 10~12 V. Therefore I'm using 4 2.7V supercapacitors in
series to gain the required voltage. When the power is available to the circuit, the caps should
be charged and they should provide power to the system in case of a power failure. This action need to be done automatically. The supercapacitors should be charged in balance, in order to be reliable. I have designed the following circuit for the purpose. I haven't simulated or prototyped it yet. I would like to know the flaws or disadvantages of using this circuit.

Also my circuit needs to be inexpensive. So I'm preferred to be my circuit very simple.
[image]

Comment: You should simulate it first. You won't damage anything. Why would you ask this question here if you have the means to simulate it and debug any basic errors?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when ready-made modules exist for exactly this purpose? Even if those modules aren't what you need it is good to learn about them to understand how they work and **why**. Julian Ilett does a lot with supercaps on his Youtube channel, he uses these modules and investigates how they work. See: https://www.youtube.com/user/julius256

Comment: Simulate what happens when the supercaps are **empty**. My guess: your transistors will blow up unless you limit the current from the supply. Hint: don't just build this and connect a 12 V supply that can deliver a lot of current as you **will** destroy some components.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks for the reply. I didn't knew such YouTube channel exists, I'll definitely try what I can learn from him. I have simulated the circuit but the results are not good. caps doesn't charge beyond 1.8V for some reason. I'll put my findings as an edit later. I think transistors won't be overloaded since there are some low ohm resistors used in series.